# Selecting specific object in queue ( ie peek +1)

Tags: c#, queue, peek

if Peek returns the next object in a queue, is there a method I can use to get a specific object?  For example, I want to find the third object in the queue and change one of its values?

right now Im just doing a foreach through the queue which might be the best solution, but I didnt know if there was something special you can use with peek?  ie Queue.Peek(2)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to access elements directly (with an `O(1)` operation), use an array instead of a queue because a queue has a different function (FIFO).

**A random access operation on a queue will be `O(n)`** because it needs to iterate over every element in the collection...which in turn makes it sequential access, rather than direct random access.

---

Then again, since you're using C#, you can use `queue.ElementAt(n)` from `System.Linq` (since `Queue` implements `IEnumerable`) but that won't be `O(1)` i.e. it will still iterate over the elements.

Comment: Accessing a random element in a queue implemented with a cyclic buffer, like `Queue<T>`, is an `O(1)` operation. `Queue<T>` even has a `GetElement(int)` method that does that, but unfortunately it's marked as `internal`. Of course one can implement their own queue class that allows random access, or use the [`CircularQueue<T>`](https://github.com/sestoft/C5/blob/master/C5/arrays/CircularQueue.cs) class from the [C5 Generic Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) which has an `O(1)` enqueue, dequeue, and item random access (and even push and pop).

Comment: This only applies to the built-in queue class. The .NET Queue<T> class does not expose an indexer, but obviously you can compute the index of the nth item... `function peek(n) { return _buffer[ (currentIndex + n) % _buffer.length ];` A different implementation could easily provide this functionality.

Answer (score 10):

Although this is still O(n), it's certainly easier to read if you use the LINQ extention methods `ElementAt()` or `ElementAtOrDefault()`, these are extentions of `IEnumerable<T>`, which `Queue<T>` implements.

```
using System.Linq;

Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
T result; 
result = queue.ElementAt(2);
result = queue.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
```

**Edit**
If you do go with the other suggestions of converting your Queue to an array just for this operation that you need to decide if the likely sizes of your queue and the distance of the index you'll be looking for from the start of your queue justify the O(n) operation of calling .ToArray(). ElementAt(m), not to mention the space requirements of creating a secondary storage location for it.

Comment: @Andreas: Good point, I had just used object as an example, edited to use generic parameter.

Answer (score 4):

foreach through a queue. Kind of a paradox.

However, if you can foreach, it is an IEnumerable, so the usual linq extensions apply:

```
queue.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()
```

or

```
queue.ElementAt(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this as a one off:

```
object thirdObjectInQueue = queue.ToArray()[2];
```

I wouldn't recommend using it a lot, however, as it copies the whole queue to an array, thereby iterating over the whole queue anyway.

Comment: This one is especially useful if one has to get multiple elements.

Comment: This is an awful idea but since you recognized that I won't down vote